# Get latest Twitter post on website

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget

I am looking to return the latest twitter post on my website in plan text, excluding retweets if possible.

Any way to do this? Preferably with JS and not PHP.

E.g
Latest Tweet: Check out stack overflow. *Posted 21 hours ago*

Comment: You might find some details here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but someone may have a better answer.

In order to use the Twitter API service via JavaScript. Your going to need to look through this.
https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview

You can also use the Twitter widgets, but it's pretty limiting.
https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new

I would recommend the PHP route since you would get a little more cache layering support if you use a stable PHP dependency to deal with the grunt work of Oauth, plus you would get a lot more in the long run.